# 'firstyearpop' for `pop.sim` in `demography` package

Tags: r, simulation, population

I'm using R `demography` package to study Mauritian population. However, I'm having some problem with `pop.sim` function as I can't figure out how the mid year population must be entered? Can anyone give me an example please?

Comment: I've tried pop.sim(mort.fcast, fert.fcast, firstyearpop="1286051")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The help file is rather brief (sorry about that). The first year population should be part of a `demogdata` object. The example at the end of the help page on `pop.sim` should help. It requires the `addb` package which is available from http://robjhyndman.com/software/addb/.

Comment: Hello sir. Thanks for your helpful answer. The first year pop is ok now but I'm getting "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'y' not found" .  Same as when I'm trying the example provided on Australia. I'm trying hard to figure out where this error is coming from. Do you have any suggestion please?

Comment: Yes, you are right sir. I've found out that it works perfectly in R2.14.2. The error message appears on the latest version of R ( 2.15.3 ). That's quite strange. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help sir.

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest versions of all packages. I am using 2.15.3 and it does NOT cause an error.

Comment: Ok sir. I shall look into it again. May be there has been a problem during the installation process of R. Thanks again for your time.